# Calling member variable through a variable?

Tags: php

I have two classes and I am going to create an object from any one of these classes(based on some conditions), say classes are `A` and `B`
and creating the object '$object' from any of these classes. These classes have some member variables, say `A` has `product_id` and `B` has `employee_name`. Can I call a member variable in following way (I am getting a parse error now.)

```
$object = new A; // or B;
$a = "product_id";// or "employee_name";

$object->$a = value;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in `{}` to tell PHP that it should first evaluate the value of `$a`, and use it's value to find the property in the class.

```
$object->{$a} = "some value;
```

Here's a [demo](http://codepad.org/aj8YuON7)

Answer (score 1):

Would this work:

```
$object->{$a} = value;
```